# plupload - download/remove the uploaded file

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

i'm using the Plupload to upload files to my server

i cant find any documentation to get back/remove the file ( download/remove the uploaded file )

i'm searching a long time, i'm getting crazy right know!

can anyone help me, if this realy exist, like a API from Plupload ?

thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

dont need any more, i hava found just what i need: [Elfinder](http://elfinder.org/)